# Game engine animation management

Tags: animation

Usually in a game scene there might be tens of animations going on at the same time, each being in its own state. I wonder usually how is this managed in game engines? Do they just stack a variable indicating the state of the animation on entity? Or do they use a separate animation system to keep all states?

Comment: Are you talking of how engines handle the data behind the scenes? Similar to how each object/class can have it's own variables, it also has it's own animation states. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @TomTsagk Yes. So I can imagine a game with a lot of animations going on at the same time. Each animation has its own timeline, and can be cancelled by game logic. I wonder usually how game engine holds those state?

Answer (score 1):

In unity it is handled with a node system.  each node is an animation you made earlier, and you connect them in the order you want them to be played.
You can also control when they are played by scripts, and then the node system gets more complicated with transitions.  you can set a transition to occur when a boolean is true, or false, or when an integer is equal to 0 or 1 or less than or greater than etc.